# how to plug devices using same pins on raspberry pi at the same time? / Raspberry Pi 4 Model B

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

[image: fan pins]
[image: lcd pins]

lcd and fan use the same pin, how can i use two devices at the same time?

Comment: Looks like there's no easy way to do this https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=5281

Comment: You mean the ground pin in this case? There's plenty of other ground pins as well, just use another one of them. Or solder the wires together. You didn't show the wire you use for the display, but if that one has individual wires, you can just move the black one for instance to pin 9.

Comment: @AlexanderBielby That is about using multiple UARTs, not about connecting two completely different things (such as a display and a fan). Besides, that thread is way outdated and not valid for the Pi4.

Comment: LCD display pins look like this https://www.amazon.com/WIshioT-Nextion-Enhanced-NX8048K070-Raspberry/dp/B079177F98

Comment: i need to build a hmi with raspberry pi. I can take your advice on this

Comment: You can connect the black (ground) wire to any pin that's named "Ground". They're all identical.

Comment: @PMF Thank you for help, if the fan is not working, what could be the reason other than the fan broken?

Comment: If the fan is connected to 5V and Ground, it should just work. There are few other things that could be wrong then, besides the fan being broken.

Comment: can u check this question to? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69751469/raspberry-pi-sd-card-format-and-install-problem @PMF

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to use 2 devices on Pi's pin 6(Ground). There is 7 more Ground pins. Just connect black wire to of other pins.

In the image yellow mark is the conflict pin and the red cicles are alternatives.

[image]