# Raspberry Pi sd card format and install problem

Tags: raspberry-pi, operating-system, format, sd-card, raspberry-pi4

I formatted my sd card first to install raspberry pi. Then I installed the raspberry pi operating system on the sd card with imager. But after the installation is finished it asks me to format the sd card again. If I don't format it, I get a format warning every time I insert the card. when I plug it on the raspberry pi like this, the act flashes irregularly at first, then it flashes rhythmically with a reduced light. I need help and advice

Answer (score 1):

It is completely normal that you get that format warning if you use the flashed card in Windows. The card is partitioned with several partitions that have a file system Windows cannot read. The Raspberry Pi needs them exactly like that, though. So after writing the image using the imager, just remove the SD card from the Windows PC and insert it into the Raspi. Except for creating a backup, you'll never need to insert it into the Windows PC again.

Comment: If this is normal, why can't I view the installation steps on the screen? i have a screen with vga, i use a converter that converts from vga to micro hdmi. @PMF

Comment: You mean that after you insert the SD card into the Raspi, you see nothing at all?

Comment: yes just a black screen and sometimes no signal warning

Comment: Could it be because of my problem with sd card or is it some other problem? how do i know?

Comment: Sometimes, a configuration entry is required for the screen, but there should normally still be _something_ visible on it. Are you sure your vga adapter is working?

Comment: Arrived by courier today ,i wasn't sure, a project will be made with a raspberry pi at work and they asked me to install it. I do not have any electronic information. Everyone can handle this easily, but I encountered a lot of problems. If I'm bothering you, let me know. @PMF

Comment: a blue light started to flash on the black screen but the setup screen still did not come.

Comment: Is there some documentation for this adapter? It's very hard to guess what could be wrong from a distance.

Comment: I had to change the config file. The problem is solved, but I will prefer to buy an hdmi monitor because I had the opportunity to try it on an hdmi monitor and I installed the operating system. Thanks for your help. Now that I've dealt with this problem, it's time to face bigger problems.

Comment: @AhmetAktepe I whish you luck there. The Raspberry Pi is a powerful device, but this doesn't make it always easy to use.